# Using rewrite for my own equality?

Tags: idris

I have the following definition of equality:

```
data Equal : x -> y -> Type where
    Reflexive : Equal a a
```

Whenever I want to use the `rewrite` syntax, I need something of type `(a = b)`, so i created:

```
makeEquitable : Equal x y -> x = y
makeEquitable Reflexive = Refl
```

Now I can do `makeEquitable (_ : Equal a b)` which I can then use to `rewrite` things. I would like to simplify this and I looked into `replace` which I don't really understand `replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y`. This `P` thing is a built-in Idris property I assume - how would I make such function for my own definition `Equality` - would it also be possible to "bake-in" something special so that `rewrite` would magically work for `Equal a b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `:set showimplicits` in the repl, you see the implicit arguments for `:t replace`:

```
replace : {a : Type} -> {x : a} -> {y : a} -> {P : a -> Type} ->
          ((=) {A = a} {B = a} x y) -> P x -> P y
```

There is nothing special about `P`, it is just an implicit argument: a predicate `P` that holds over values of type `a`. Most types of these implicit arguments can be inferred, so your function could look like:

```
replaceEqual : {P : a -> Type} -> Equal x y -> P x -> P y
replaceEqual Reflexive prf = prf
```

But you cannot easily make your own `rewrite` as far as I know. However, you can use a syntax rule to prettify your approach:

```
syntax eqrewrite [a] "in" [b] = rewrite makeEquitable a in b;

plus_commutes_Z' : Equal m (plus m 0)
plus_commutes_Z' {m = Z} = Reflexive
plus_commutes_Z' {m = (S k)} =
  let rec = plus_commutes_Z' {m=k}
  in eqrewrite rec in Reflexive
```